# Fire when ENTER key pressed in dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When dialog opens I focus it with `$(this).parents( ...` and when ENTER key is pressed it should execude but it's not. How to execute it when ENTER key pressed?

```
            open: function() { 
                $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)').focus();
                $("#DIALOG2").keydown(function(event) {
                    if (event.which == 13) { //EXECUTE!
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        ajax_usun(del_id);
                    }
                });             
            }
```

JSfiddle with example: (click on delete button and instaed of pressing buttons in dialog with mouse press enter - nothing happens) http://jsfiddle.net/FkbLT/2/

Comment: What does it prints if you put an else to: 

if (event.which == 13) { //EXECUTE!....} else { alert (event.which); }
?

And if you try with keypress instead of keydown ?

Comment: It's not even firing an alert. Keydown has issues with brwoser compatibility hasn't?

Comment: No, it's expected to enter in IF, not in ELSE, this just proved that you have nothing "in the middle" that can change your which code... 
Can you share a JSFiddle with html and javascript inside ? Tnx

Comment: @Swift http://jsfiddle.net/FkbLT/2/, more described in edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I've found out the problem.

```
            show: 'scale',
```

is causing the focus to not be applied, probably because it tries (and fails) to apply the focus when the "scale" effect is still running, then when scale effect is over, you have no focus on the button.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VjakR/

EDIT 2: DEFINITELY a JQuery Bug, i've tried all the 'show' possible settings, and it turned out that it works with:

```
blind
clip
drop
fold
puff
slide
size
pulsate
```

while it breaks with:

```
scale
explode
```

Just choose another one, and/or report this bug to JQuery developers...

Comment: I have found a jQuery BUG in 3rd day of using it? yay! Lika a Pr0. @Swift have you reported it?

Comment: Like a boss :) No, i've not yet reported this, but you can do it too ^^

Comment: Who gives 'BOSS' badges in stackoverflow?